# ¿Cómo ignorar elementos repetidos en un arreglo y pasarlos a otro?

Tags: c++, array

No se cómo hacer una función que elimine un numero repetido en un arreglo los que he mirado se me hacen complejos y no los he entendido, ¿alguien podría hacer un ejemplo para que pueda implementarlo en un arreglo?

Aquí esta el código del proyecto que estoy realizando espero que no haya problema:

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

//ejemplo
//entrada 
//int m[4]={1,2,2,3};
//salida
//int m{1,2,3};

using namespace std;

int aleatory_ip(int ip){

    volatile new int n1[ip];
    volatile new int n2[ip];
    volatile new int n3[ip];
    volatile new int n4[ip];
         
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    for (int i = 0; i != ip; ++i)
    {

      n1[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
      n2[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
      n3[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
      n4[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
  
     }

     volatile string IPs[ip];
     volatile int *conn;

    for (int i = 0; i != ip; ++i){

     IPs[i] = to_string(n1[i]) + '.' +
              to_string(n2[i]) + '.' +
              to_string(n3[i]) + '.' +
              to_string(n4[i]) ;

     }

     cout<<"[$:created IPs]";

     for (int i = 0 int k = 0; i !=ip k! =ip ; ++i ++k){

       if (IPs[i]=="127.0.0.0   ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="0.0.0.0     ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="3.0.0.0     ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="15.0.0.0    ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="56.0.0.0    ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="10.0.0.0    ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="192.168.0.0 ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="172.16.0.0  ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="100.64.0.0  ")
        continue;
       if (IPs[i]=="198.18.0.0  ")
        continue;
       else{IPs[i]=IPs[k];}
     }

      cout<<"[$:corriged IPs]";
  
    for (int i = 0 ; i != ip ; ++i){
      
      conn = &(IPs[i]);   

     } 

    for (const auto &IP : IPs){
        
     cout <<"[aleatory_ip $]:"<< IP << '\n';
        
     } 

    return IPs;
    
 }
int main(){
  

  int T;
  cin>>T; 
  aleatory_ip(T);
   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: En c ó c++???..

Comment: De ser C++, si no te interesa meterte con ningún algoritmo, usar un `unordered_set`, una estructura que no admite duplicados

Comment: @Christian c++ ok

Comment: @Mateo gracias,pero prefiero algun algoritmo

Comment: Y que has intentado? Aquí no te resolverán la tarea. Te ayudaremos con los problemas que tengas con tu código y aquí no muestras ningún código

Comment: @Christian no espero que me resuelvan el ejercicio solo busco algún algoritmo que pueda implementar en un proyecto a mayor escala,he intentado condicionales ,por eso edite la pregunta

Comment: que tiene que ver el generar IPs aleatorias con borrar elementos repetidos??

Comment: @Christian que si se generar ips repetidas hay saltarselas y las que no estan repetidas pasarlas a otro arreglo

Comment: En ese caso solo tendrías que verificar si la IP generada se encuentra dentro de tu array

Comment: @Christian no te entiendo, podrías poner un ejemplo

Comment: no soy experto en c++ pero espero que mi respuesta te ayude un poco

Comment: @Christian ok cristian gracias ,me dio un poco de idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aquí esta el código del proyecto que estoy realizando espero que no haya problema

Lo hay, hay muchos problemas.

- Las cabeceras `<stdlib.h>`, `<time.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<signal.h>`, `<errno.h>` son de C y no deben usarse en C++. Para cada una de ellas existe una versión portada a C++: `<cstdlib>`, `<ctime>`, `<cstring>`, `<cstdlib>`, `<csignal>`, `<cerrno>` y son las que deberías usar en caso de ser necesarias, que en el código que has compartido ninguna de ellas lo es.
- La cabecera `conio.h` no forma parte de las [librerías estándar de C](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/header), es una utilidad proveída por el compilador de la plataforma, que declara varias funciones para permitir al usuario interactuar con la consola y las funciones proveídas varían entre compiladores y plataformas, en definitiva no sigue ni el [ANSI C](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) ni el [POSIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).
- El calificador `volatile` se usa para indicarle al compilador que no optimice escrituras de esos datos, ese calificador no tiene importancia a no ser que estés en un entorno multihilo, que no parece ser tu caso.
- Estas líneas ni siquiera compilan:

  ```
  volatile new int n1[ip];
  volatile new int n2[ip];
  volatile new int n3[ip];
  volatile new int n4[ip];
  ```

  Posiblemente querías hacer esto:

  ```
  volatile int *n1 = new int[ip];
  volatile int *n2 = new int[ip];
  volatile int *n3 = new int[ip];
  volatile int *n4 = new int[ip];
  ```
- Esta línea no es C++ estándar:

  ```
  volatile string IPs[ip];
  ```

  Eso es una formación<sup>1</sup> de tamaño variable (*variable length array* o VLA en inglés). En C++ y C las formaciones que no usan memoria dinámica deben crearse con un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, `ip` al ser una variable contiene un valor conocido en tiempo de ejecución. Lee [estos hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla) para saber más del tema.
- Esta línea ni siquiera compila, le faltan comas y al menos un operador de comparación:

  ```
  for (int i = 0 int k = 0; i !=ip k! =ip ; ++i ++k)
  //            ^                 ^            ^
  ```
- Esta línea ni siquiera compila:

  ```
  conn = &(IPs[i]);
  ```

  La variable `conn` es un puntero a entero (`int *`) mientras que la expresión `&(IPs[i])` es un puntero a cadena (`string *`).

Una vez mencionado todo eso, te hago saber que C++ dispone de varios contenedores de datos que no permiten duplicados, si guardas información en cualquiera de ellos los duplicados serán eliminados sin que tengas que programar nada, por ejemplo todos los contenedores de la familia *set* ([`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)), el siguiente código:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> IPs {"0.0.0.0", "255.255.255.255", "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"};

    for (const auto &IP : IPs)
        std::cout << IP << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[Genera la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##VY3dCoJAEIWvnacYDFIxJYUIdOu@Ox8giGVdZSF3ZX@uoldvUwsyhhk43@GcYeOY9Yx5vxGS3V3LkTipdMs1b2@G2zP8DGO1kP2aCDUxToczgJAWBypknMADAmPbqvorIgv6VuClMfgI9/ky4Q7D8nDIVzujojwufvEvnjVA0CmNMVPSWKTOKtxeGqzm1gSCz3OmnEVCJjbf6CqjOae5dVrivoan9y/W3WlvfDYFTixNS/oG):

```
127.0.0.1
255.255.255.255
0.0.0.0
```

Como puedes ver, la entrada `"127.0.0.1"` estaba repetida, pero sólo ha aparecido una vez al listar el contenido. Ten en cuenta que `"127.0.0.1"` y `"127.0.0.1      "` contarán como entradas diferentes.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*-

Comment: gracias ,no sabia que cometia tantos errores

Comment: gracias por todo pero la idea es excluir a esas ip no mostrarlas por pantalla

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo "*excluir a esas ip*" ¿qué ip? Tu pregunta es sobre elementos repetidos, no sobre excluir determinados elementos.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1};
    std::vector<int>::iterator last;

    last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()); 
                                        
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != last; ++it) {
         std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. no sabes que lenguaje se usa en la pregunta 2. explica tu respuesta