# Error al usar el operador ternario

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente código donde el error está en el operador ternario dentro de un bloque `for`, debido a que si el caso es verdadero uso la sentencia `continue`; que continua con la siguiente iteración del bucle.

Pero no funciona el operador dice que hay `"error en la expresión antes del continue"` y no se cuál es el error que dice que es antes debido a que ya encapsulé las expresiones, ¿alguien sabe como solucionarlo ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void aleatory_ip(long ip){

    volatile int n1[ip];
    volatile int n2[ip];
    volatile int n3[ip];
    volatile int n4[ip];
   
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    
    int j = 0;
    int t = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != ip; ++i)
    {

      n1[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
      n2[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
      n3[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
      n4[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
  
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < ip ; ++i)
     {

       (n1[i] >= 0 and n1[i] <= 255) ? continue; : n1[i] = 0 + rand() % (255);
       (n2[i] >= 0 and n2[i] <= 255) ? continue; : n2[i] = 0 + rand() % (255);
       (n3[i] >= 0 and n3[i] <= 255) ? continue; : n3[i] = 0 + rand() % (255);
       (n4[i] >= 0 and n4[i] <= 255) ? continue; : n4[i] = 0 + rand() % (255);

     }

      string IPs[ip];
      string IPa[ip];   

    for (int i = 0; i != ip; ++i){

     IPs[i] = to_string(n1[i]) + '.' +
              to_string(n2[i]) + '.' +
              to_string(n3[i]) + '.' +
              to_string(n4[i]);

     }

     cout<<"[server:][$:created IPs]"<<endl;
    
     for (int i = 0; i !=ip ; ++i){

        if (IPs[i]=="127.0.0.0"  )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="0.0.0.0"    )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="3.0.0.0"    )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="15.0.0.0"   )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="56.0.0.0"   )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="10.0.0.0"   )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="192.168.0.0")
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="172.16.0.0" )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="100.64.0.0" )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="127.0.0.10" )
        continue;
        if (IPs[i]=="198.18.0.0" )
        continue;
       else{

         IPa[j] = IPs[i];
         j++;

       }
     }
     for (int i = 0; i !=ip; ++i)
     {
        IPs[i] = IPa[i];
     }
     for (int i = 0; i != ip ; ++i)
     {
        t += sizeof(IPs[i]);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i)
     {
         for (j = i+1; j < ip; ++j)
         {
            if(IPs[i] == IPs[j])
            {
                 k = j; 

                 while(k < ip)
                {
                   IPs[k] = IPs[k+1];
                   ++k;
                }
 
                 --ip;
                 --j;

             }
         }
     }

    
     
    for (const auto &IP : IPs){
        
     cout <<"[server:][aleatory_ip $]:"<< IP << '\n';
     Sleep(1000);

     }  
 }
void test_case(){

  long T;
  cin>>T; 
  aleatory_ip(T);
  
 } 
int main(){
  
  test_case();
   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y porque motivo no usas un if normal? La expresion que va ahi
tiene que retornar un valor. La unica excepcion es si estas
lanzando una excepcion.

Comment: Saludos. Particularmente yo uso los operadores ternarios para obtener un valor no para ejecutar una sentencia como el `continue;` que estas usando. La asignación que colocas después de `:` por ser **c++** te lo permite. Si las asignaciones de tus `N` se realizaran si la condición no se cumple mejor usa `if`. **Nota** no veo la razón el `continue;` a mi parecer se cumpla o no la condición el ciclo seguira hasta que `i>=ip` no antes.

Answer (score 3):

No entiendes el funcionamiento del operador ternario.

---

El operador ternario es una **expresión** que **devuelve un valor**. En otras palabras, al evaluar un operador ternario el resultado debe ser un valor.

La instrucción `continue` no es un valor, la instrucción `continue` no se puede interpretar como un valor, la expresión `continue` no puede substituir a un valor en ningún contexto.

Pero ese es el menor de tus problemas, tu código tiene errores de concepto y de algoritmo. Vamos a echarle un vistazo:

- **Estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pero incluyes cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c)**: `<string.h>`,  `<stdlib.h>` y `<time.h>` son cabeceras de C y no deben ser usadas en C++.

  - Si realmente necesitases cabeceras de C en tu programa (lo cuál no es tu caso) deberías usar las versiones portadas a C++: `<cstring>`, `<cstdlib>` y `<ctime>`.
- **El cualificador `volatile` es inutil en este contexto**: El cualificador `volatile` se usa para indicarle a el compilador que esa variable no debe someterse a optimizaciones que podrían afectar a un sistema concurrente. Tu código no es concurrente, no necesitas `volatile`.
- **Tanto en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) como en [c](/questions/tagged/c) las formaciones<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática<sup>2</sup> deben definirse con un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación**: En tu caso estás usando una variable, cuyo valor sólo se conoce en tiempo de ejecución, para definir las formaciones<sup>1</sup> `n1`, `n2`, `n3` y `n4`.
- **Las variables deben tener nombres autoexplic**...

Mira, lo dejo ya. Es muy frustrante que la gente dedique tiempo a corregir problemas que tiene tu código y tú no des muestra alguna de haber entendido lo que se escribe y redactes una pregunta con exactamente los mismos problemas que ya se te señalaron anteriormente.

Varios de los fallos que cometes, cometiste y te empeñas en repetir, te han sido señalados en otras respuestas:

- [¿Cómo convertir stringstream en un arreglo que pueda iterarar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463751/hola-alguien-sabe-como-puedo-convertir-stringstream-o-en-un-arreglo-que-pueda-i)
- [¿Cómo ignorar elementos repetidos en un arreglo y pasarlos a otro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/470979/c%C3%B3mo-ignorar-elementos-repetidos-en-un-arreglo-y-pasarlos-a-otro)

**Por favor, lee y entiende lo que te responden al menos tan en serio como quienes dedicaron su tiempo a intentar aportarte algo, intento que al menos en tu caso, ha sido una pérdida de tiempo**.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

<sup>2</sup>La memoria automática es la que no se pide con `new`.